# Empty collection literal requires an explicit type

Tags: swift, xcode

Who can help me out:

[image]

Why is the above oke?

[image]

and is this not oke? It was in an older version of Xcode, but not anymore. By the way the app runs correctly ignoring the warning. But I like to understand how to fix this?

Comment: `set([[String]](), ...` or `[Data]()`, why not use the var?

Comment: The "above" is OK because it provides an explicit type. That's what the `[[String]]` and `[Data]` are giving. So the compiler know what the `[]` represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the comment op @Larme was the right answer. So:

```
[[String]]()
```

in code:

```
appGroup!.set([[String]](), forKey: ...)
```

Thx!